# How to add Bottom Navigation View in all the activities in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am developing an android app it has many activities and I decided to use the bottom navigation view to make the user interface more attractive. But I have a problem that I need to put this bottom navigation view in all the activity and for this, I need to put the view in every XML file and also needs to bind that view in every class file. So is there any way that I need to create the bottom navigation view one time and it shows in all the activity and no need to bind every time in java? And it shows up in all the activities.

Comment: Yoj can create a botton navigation in a separate single xml then include it where ever you want.

Comment: do I need to bind that view in every class file or only one time?

Comment: `So is there any way that I need to create the bottom navigation view one time` use fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. Make NavigationActivity and change all Activities to Fragments. Then you can use all Activities in `ViewPager`

Option 2. If you use `ViewBinding` (what you probably should) make NavigationBottomView as own class and use own layout for it. Then iin each activity you need `include` in `xml` and create new Instance of your `NavigationBottomView`

Answer (score 0):

No, You can create new layout.xml and include it in every activities layout and bind save as extension if you are using kotlin, but i have a question, why are you using many activities, Single activity pattern is the best.

Comment: Every activity has different layouts and different working how can I use single activity for all?

Comment: @youcantseeme, with [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments)

Comment: I dont know your case, but i think you can use fragment pretty simple.

Comment: `Single activity pattern is the best.` that is your opinion, unless you can provide actual source for it :)